# How to access textfield defined in popup.html from content scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

The title says it all, I am very new to chrome extensions(this is my first extension).

I am making a basic extension which has a simple text field and I want to show its content as an alert on page load.

My popup.html looks like:

```
  <html>
  <body>
      <p>Name: <input type="text" id="test" value="Mickey Mouse"></p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and my content script has:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Value: " + $("#test").val());
  });
```

and manifest.json is:

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":...
     ,

    "browser_action": {...
     },

     "content_scripts": [
     {
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
         "js": ["jquery.js","script.js"]
     }
     ]
  }
```

but the webpage always shows:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the alert to appear when the popup is shown or when any page is loaded in a tab ?

Comment: First of all my apologies for this questions...I now understand that I need to establish communication between content script and popup page via message passing...How can I do that? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You cannot access a field in popup unless the popup is visible. As soon as it loses focus and gets hidden, it is unloaded so you can't access it anymore. What exactly are you trying to achieve (utlimately) ?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to access the value of an input that is defined on `popup.html` from a content script will never work. Remember that content scripts can view the DOM of the page that they are injected into and **nothing** else. (In your example, the text input is stored within the DOM of `popup.html`).

One way to get around this is to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). So, from within `popup.html` you can send a message containing the value of the text input to a content script using the message passing API.

In `popup.html` you will need to send a message to a content script. You will need to know the tabId of the tab that you want to send the message to...as a simple example something like this will send the text input contents to **ALL** active tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
  for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {txt : $("#test").val()}, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
});
```

And if your content script you will need a listener, something like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  //Do stuff with the request here
  console.log(request);
}
```

Comment: The snippet above will not send a message to **ALL** active tabs; just to the first active tab of the window where the popup is displayed on. Furthermore, `chrome.extension.onMessage` is deprecated; `chrome.runtime.onMessage` should be used instead.

Comment: You are correct, of course. I have edited the answer with your corrections.